# finding the value of A when normal distribution is given as μ

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that the mean of a normal distribution is **μ**. If **μ ± Aσ contains 77.76%** of all the data, then what is the value of A?

how should I start solving this question?

Comment: Hint: Note that $\mu \pm A\sigma$ is symmetric around the mean, thus your area of 0.7776 is centered at the mean. That also means the area _not_ included is equally split left/right.

Comment: @tabstop: μ should be 50% since it's split equally. So A should be 77.76%-50%=27.76, which means that the total A is .2276 * 2= .5552?

Comment: "$\mu$ should be 50%" -- this isn't true (as you have it written).  It means that 50% of the area will be to the left of $\mu$ and 50% will be to the right.  And since they _tell_ you that the area is 0.7776, trying to calculate the area seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the standard deviation is $\sigma$. As always, start by writing down your problem mathematically, as much as you can. Your have a distribution

$$X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$

and you are told

$$P(\mu - A\sigma < X < \mu + A\sigma) = 77.76\%\;\;\;(\dagger)$$

now when working with normal probabilities, you only know the probabilities for the standard normal distribution, so write an equivalent probability statement for

$$Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$$

where

$$Z \sim N(0,1)$$

To do this, substitute $X=\sigma Z + \mu$ into $(\dagger)$ and simplify to get rid of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Finally, you have a probability statement for $Z$, and you will need to manipulate this into a form where you can use lookup tables or statistical software to get your answer. For this you can use @tabstop's comment and/or sketch the normal distribution and the area you need and you symmetry properties.

Your sketch should look like this except prettier

[image]

The shaded area is the probability, 0.7776, that you have been given in the question. Your task is to find $A$ so that the vertical lines at $-A$ on the left of the area and at $A$ on the right of the area are positioned such that the area is 0.7776.

Comment: ok, so basically you have to look up the number of .7776, since Z=(X-μ)/σ= (.7776-0)/1= .7776?

Comment: Why N is (0,1)?

Comment: You're trying to _find_ $Z$.  The _area_ is 0.7776 (as area under the curve corresponds to probability), and we certainly don't know $X$.

Comment: N is just any old normal distribution. N(0,1) is the standard normal distribution with mean zero and standard deviation=variance=1. As @tabstop says, we don't know the probability distribution X you have been given so we have to transform it to a N(0,1) distribution which we can reason about probabilistically.